# gradle checkstyle configuration isn't being applied via precompiled plugin

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin, checkstyle

I've got a small gradle project which has two small Java applications as subprojects. I'm trying to enforce the checkstyle plugin on all subprojects, so I've created a small precompiled plugin for verification and then applied it to the subprojects. I took all of this from [the checkstyle example from the gradle documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html#sec:precompiled_plugins) and [the checkstyle plugin documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/checkstyle_plugin.html#sec:checkstyle_project_layout).

**Project structure**:

```
project
  buildSrc
    build.gradle
    src/
      main/
        groovy/
          com.company.verify.gradle
  config/
    checkstyle/
      checkstyle.xml
      suppressions.xml
  sub1/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
  sub2/
    build.gradle
    settings.gradle
  build.gradle  (root)
  settings.gradle  (root)
```

**Root settings.gradle**

```
rootProject.name = 'my-app'
include ("sub1", "sub2")
```

**buildSrc/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'groovy-gradle-plugin'
}
```

**buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com.company.verify.gradle**

```
plugins {
    id 'checkstyle'
}

checkstyle {
    toolVersion = "10.3.3"
    ignoreFailures = false
    maxWarnings = 0
}
```

**sub1/build.gradle**

```
plugins {
  id 'com.company.verify'
}

// Subproject 1 has some generated code we don't want checked
checkstyle {
    checkstyleMain.excludes = ["**/generated/**"]
}
```

However, when I run `./gradlew clean checkstyleMain --stack`, it's obvious that the `toolVersion: 10.3.3` directive isn't being applied:

```
Execution failed for task ':sub1:checkstyleMain'.
  > A failure occurred while executing org.gradle.api.plugins.quality.internal.CheckstyleAction
    > Unable to create Root Module: config {/path/to/project/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml}, classpath {null}.
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:/path/to/project/config/checkstyle/checkstyle.xml; lineNumber: 22; columnNumber: 4; The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

This is happening because the `toolVersion: 10.3.3` in `com.company.verify.gradle` isn't being applied to the subproject, and so checkstyle is using a different toolVersion which expects checkstyle.xml to be formatted differently. However, when I remove the precompiled plugin and apply the checkstyle plugin and configuration options directly to `sub1`, `./gradlew checkstyleMain` passes without any problems.

Can anyone tell me what's going on here? Why aren't configurations from checkstyle being passed from the precompiled plugin to the subprojects applying it? If I can't figure this out, I will be forced to duplicate all of my checkstyle configurations in every subproject, and I really don't want to do that.